# Can't force close app without it restarting?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm using this code to force close my app after 1 second. But the problem is that it restarts itself after closing! How can I make it close permanently?

```
  private fun endApp() {

    val handler = Handler()
    handler.postDelayed({ Process.sendSignal(Process.myPid(), Process.SIGNAL_KILL) }, 1000)
  }
```

Comment: My guess is that this is because when you kill the process android asumes the app has crashed and automatically restarts it. If thats the problem the solution would be to find another way to exit the app without killing the process in that manner. Check if this works: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-quit-application-programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this method to force exit your app:

```
fun exitApp() {
    moveTaskToBack(true);
    exitProcess(0)
}
```

> [exitProcess(status: Int)](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.system/exit-process.html): Terminates the currently running
> process.
>
> [moveTaskToBack (boolean nonRoot)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#moveTaskToBack(boolean)) Move the task containing this
> activity to the back of the activity stack. The activity's order
> within the task is unchanged.

or

> [finishAffinity()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#finishAffinity()): Finish this activity as well as all activities
> immediately below it in the current task that have the same affinity.
> This is typically used when an application can be launched on to
> another task (such as from an ACTION_VIEW of a content type it
> understands) and the user has used the up navigation to switch out of
> the current task and in to its own task. In this case, if the user has
> navigated down into any other activities of the second application,
> all of those should be removed from the original task as part of the
> task switch.

```
fun exitApp() {
    finishAffinity()
}
```

Comment: Your code closes my app without restarting, that is good! But an issue is that I have service running (with notification) and it closes & restarts that... (Tested on Android 8.1) So your answer solved half my problem.

Comment: To recap, `moveTaskToBack(true); exitProcess(0)` closes the app successfully but restarts its service. And `finishAffinity`closes the app but keeps its service running.

Comment: I want to close the app *AND* terminate all its services. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @Bandy have you found a solution?